# How can I push a war from windows system to boot2docker's VM tomcat webapp folder?

Tags: tomcat, docker, boot2docker

According to boot2docker docs:

The first of the following share names that exists (if any) will be automatically mounted at the location specified:

1. Users share at /Users
2. /Users share at /Users
3. c/Users share at /c/Users
4. /c/Users share at /c/Users
5. c:/Users share at /c/Users

In my case I can see an automount for c:/Users. However how do i push a war from c:/Users to the tomcat webapp folder on  the VM created by boot2docker.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-v <host-dir>:<container-dir>` option in `docker run` to share a directory between boot2docker's filesystem and container's filesystem. E.g.:

`docker run -v /Users:/war/folder tomcat`

Comment: I am trying to run:docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 -v /C/Users/AbhinavG/tomdeploy:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps tomcat

Comment: And does it work? If not what are the symptoms? Any error message?

Comment: I have my war in the folder on windows system at :
C/Users/AbhinavG/tomdeploy
I try and push it to webapps folder using the command
run:docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 -v /C/Users/AbhinavG/tomdeploy:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps tomcat

however i can't access the localhost:8080 url. I get a 404.